# Exit Form - Advantage of using "ProcessDialogKey" over "KeyUp"

Tags: c#, winforms

To close a form when ESC is pressed, I have always used:

```
protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData) //Exit form if Esc is pressed
{
    if (Form.ModifierKeys == Keys.None && keyData == Keys.Escape)
    {
        this.Close();
        return true;
    }
    return base.ProcessDialogKey(keyData);
}

private void frmMain_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) //Ask for confirmation when "X" is clicked
{
    //Define a messagebox
    const string message = "Are you sure that you want to exit the application?";
    const string caption = "Close Application";
    var result = MessageBox.Show(message, caption,
                                 MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                                 MessageBoxIcon.Question);

    //Cancel the action if NO is clicked
    e.Cancel = (result == DialogResult.No);
}
```

Today, I realised that the same can be achieved using the following code:

```
private void frmMain_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{            
    //Close form when ESC key is pressed
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}

private void frmMain_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) //Ask for confirmation when "X" is clicked
{
    //Define a messagebox
    const string message = "Are you sure that you want to exit the application?";
    const string caption = "Close Application";
    var result = MessageBox.Show(message, caption,
                                 MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                                 MessageBoxIcon.Question);

    //Cancel the action if NO is clicked
    e.Cancel = (result == DialogResult.No);
}
```

So I would like to know whether there is any advantage in following the first set of code since the second set of code seems more hassle-free.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, they are technically different (in order to the order of execution), but they will do the same thing. You don't need to be overcautious about it.

I'd use `ProcessDialogKey` because even if a control like a `TextBox` contains focus, the `ProcessDialogKey` of the `Form` will run, while in this case `KeyDown` or `KeyUp` of the `Form` will raise only if you set `KeyPreview` of the form to `true`.

So Here is the code which I will use:

```
protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == Keys.Escape)
    {
        this.Close();
        return true;
    }
    return base.ProcessDialogKey(keyData);
}
```

It's quiet [similar](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Form.cs,05717cf915c738b5) to the way that [`CancelButton`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.cancelbutton%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) works.

Comment: So then are you saying that both codes are equal if I set KeyPreview of the form to True? Because I always do so.

Comment: They are technically different (in order to the order of execution), but they will do the same thing. You don't need to be overcautious about it.

Comment: That is what I was trying to understand. Thanks, solved. I do not know whether I should mark your answer as an answer, because the question has been answered by this comment of yours, not your actual answer. Do advise on this at your convenience. Thanks

Comment: I believe the post answers your question :)

Answer (score 1):

Just to play [*devil's advocate*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devil%27s_advocate), one could argue that neither is appropriate for this function as the Form Class exposes the [Form.CancelButton Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.cancelbutton(v=vs.110).aspx) for this purpose.

> Gets or sets the button control that is clicked when the user presses the ESC key.

This property is of type `IButtonControl`. Therefore Form itself could implement that interface and serve as its own `CancelButton`.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form, IButtonControl
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CancelButton = this;
    }

    DialogResult IButtonControl.DialogResult
    {
        get {return  DialogResult.OK;}
        set {}
    }
    void IButtonControl.NotifyDefault(bool value) { }

    void IButtonControl.PerformClick()
    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Of course, if the Form presents an actual CancelButton, then it should be assigned to the Form.CancelButton Property.